# Google account gives ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT errors

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, ssl

A couple of days ago, I started being unable to connect to accounts.google.com, which handles logins to all kinds of google services.

I get this error in Chrome:

Error 126 (net::ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT): Unknown error.

[image]

In IE I get this:

[image]

I assume it is the same error, just wrapped up.

I run Win8 RTM.

On the SAME machine, using the same network card, in a VMWare workstation image running Win7, I am able to connect perfectly. On another of my machines on my network, I am also still able to connect with no problem.

My girlfriend uses the same network and has also complained a couple of times about this error (google calendar) - but this is anecdotal, since her technical troubleshooting abilities stop at "xxxx is broken". Her machine runs Win7. ;)

I have rebooted, cleared cookies, do not run any antivirus/firewall, have not changed network config. The first 3-4 days after installing Win8, I did not have any problems.

I have also searched, and found a hint about enabling SSL2.0 in connection settings, which did not help.

Anybody know something about this error and what I can do to fix it?

I blogged about the problem and setting MTU on the computer [here](http://klausjensen.com/step-by-step-solution-to-err_ssl_bad_record_mac_alert-when-trying-to-access/).

Comment: I've found this while googling: `change MTU to 1400 in router settings.`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I don't have access to fiddle with my router. And I have used this same router for 6 months.

Comment: Try doing a low level wireshark capture of the entire conversation (filter by hostname for accounts.google.com) and try to see what's wrong. Also, see if you can find a description of ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT in the OpenSSL source code.. Might be able to figure this thing out

Comment: Wireshark is not compatible with Win8 - or to be more precise - WinPCap refuses to install under Win8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some russian forum posts that suggest that setting the routers MTU to 1400 might also fix it.

[Translated with Google!](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=http://habrahabr.ru/qa/23642/&prev=/search?q=ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT%2bmtu%2b1400&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1235&bih=674&prmd=imvns&sa=X&ei=xXFPUMu8KIHv0gGlm4DwAQ&ved=0CGQQ7gEwCA)

A little ways down the page it says: **decision of** <strike>badguy</strike>: >blah< **mtu 1400 router** >blah<

You might also try setting your primary or secondary DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS) and you can adjust your MTU on your PC if you can't get into the router settings.

Comment: Do you have a source?  The way that this answer stands, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Setting MTU on the computer did the trick. Both on my own Win8 box and my GF's Win7 laptop, that started having the same problem. My landlord recently changed a switch we connect through, and I think this must be related.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it is fixed!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. According to [this forum post](http://www.luvfree.com/forums/general_discussion/i_cannot_access_to_my_gmailcom_error_126_neterr_ssl_bad_record_mac_alert_in_chro.htm), there are two ways to deal with that:

> There are two ways to solve this problem:
>
> 1. Upgrade firmware for your router. You may download the last version of firmware  from website of the manufacturer of your router.
> 2. Change "MTU" value to "1400" in your router settings.  This option is located in "IP Config" -> "WAN & LAN"

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the `ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT` error from Google Chrome, do the following:

1. Go to Device Manager Settings on your computer
2. Go to Network Adapters
3. Uninstall your WIFI network adapter by right clicking on the adapter name and selecting "Uninstall Device" the system will give you a warning, proceed.... it will then ask if you want to uninstall the software also. Select yes and uninstall.
4. Restart your computer

Once you restart your computer and log in, the system will reinstall your WiFi network adapter automatically.

Go to google chrome and navigate to the web pages that you were having the error.  The issue should be resolved.  This is the only advise that worked for me.