# Bridge Network in Windows 10 Generates ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT in Chrome

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v, ssl-certificate

I have a weird problem, for which I researched a lot, but no luck!

I have created an External Switch in Hyper-V, which in turn creates a network bridge on my Wifi adapter. I'm facing this issue that, for a specific Website, when I try to go to the login page, I see the `ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT` error in Chrome.

I have attached a screenshot: the Website is also there, in case it helps:

[image]

It's worth noting that if I right-click on my Wifi adapter and select `Remove from Bridge`, I don't get this error (of course after a required restart so that my connection works)

I have also included a screenshot of my network adapters and the `Properties` page of the network bridge; maybe that would help:

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google account gives ERR\_SSL\_BAD\_RECORD\_MAC\_ALERT errors](https://superuser.com/questions/472372/google-account-gives-err-ssl-bad-record-mac-alert-errors)

Comment: What?  I linked to a 6 year old duplicate question.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have the exact same problem for a few weeks now. I don't think this is the same error at all. Note it only happens when using the "network bridge" pseudo adapter. Unless you know how to change how this thing work? Can we configure some MTU for this bridge? It does that on all browsers. But, for information, if I use Firefox and set the its `security.tls.version.max` config option to 1 (default is 4), it works. Weird.

Comment: I actually found something that sems works for me... Go to the vEthernet that correspond to your bridge, edit its properties and configure the "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter". Change the "Large Send Offload Version 2" to Disabled for IPV4 and IPV6. Here is an image of the dialog box: https://i.imgur.com/j36AWlE.png

Comment: @SimonMourier your workaround worked for me too :) . The question is: is doing that dangerous and causes my connection to be less secure? I'm asking because I have no idea what that `Large Send Offload Version 2` does

Comment: @Farzad - it has nothing to do with security. It's more a performance feature, but actually, if you google on this, you'll see some people recommend to disable it on hyper-v because it can cause performance issue. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to the "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" configuration.

Go to the vEthernet pseudo adapter that correspond to your network bridge, edit its properties and configure the "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter". Change the "**Large Send Offload Version 2**" to `Disabled` for IPV4 and IPV6, like this:

[image]

You don't have to reboot, it should work as soon as you accept this new configuration.